# How to maintain how many failed login attempts made by user in a session spring

Tags: session, spring-mvc, spring-security

My requirement is , i want to lock a user if user tries to login more than 3 times with wrong credentials in a session. I want to store the count in a (pre authenticated ) session.

I am using form authentication

spring-security.xml

```
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
   <security:logout logout-success-url="/" />
```

Login Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() throws Exception {
    return new ModelAndView(UrlRegistry.SIMPLEFI_LOGIN_PAGE);
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/loginFailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginFailed() {
     return new ModelAndView(UrlRegistry.SIMPLEFI_LOGIN_PAGE, "error", "true");
    }
```

From search. I got to know about use of ApplicationListener , but there I can't access the session object so can't store the count there.

Can any one suggest how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to store the count in the session? That could be easily circumvented by an attacker by simply omitting the session id from the requests. Anyway, if you are not concerned about that...

Try implementing a custom [`AuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html), which is a call-back interface defining a single method: `onAuthenticationFailure()`. This method receives both the request object and the exception instance that caused the authentication to fail, hence it provides an ideal extension point to add your functionality.

If you want to keep the standard behavior (redirect the request to a specific page), don't forget to wrap or extend the default implementation (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`).

Here is some help on how to wire up your custom handler:

```
<security:http ...>
    ...
    <security:form-login
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAFH"
    ...
    />
</security:http>

<bean id="customAFH" class="CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    ...
</bean>
```